# Parsing JSON string using Jackson API

Tags: java, json, vert.x, jackson2, jackson-databind

I am using Jackson API in Vert.x core bundle to decode a JSON string to a java object. Normally this works in almost all cases but for one particular use case. I am constructing the JSON string from the user entered form data and using below line to map it to a java object.

```
MyClass myClass = io.vertx.core.json.Json.mapper.readValue(jsonString, MyClass.class)
```

**MyClass.java**

```
public class MyClass{
    private String ID;
    private String description;

    //getter and setter methods
}
```

**Input string**

```
{
    "description": "“success”,\n “data”: [\n   {\n     “severity”: “2\",\n     “createdby”: “Online user\",\n     “product”: “Google map”,\n     “description”: “test”,",
    "ID": "74085652"
}
```

**When the value of the field `description`** **is another JSON string** then the mapping fails with an exception.

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Unexpected character ('“' (code 8220 / 0x201c)): was expecting either valid name character (for unquoted name) or double-quote (for quoted) to start field name
```

I have tried adding these `com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser.Feature` configurations but it didn't work.

```
    Json.mapper.configure(ALLOW_UNQUOTED_CONTROL_CHARS, true);
    Json.mapper.configure(ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES, true);
    Json.mapper.configure(ALLOW_BACKSLASH_ESCAPING_ANY_CHARACTER, true);
```

I am using **Vert.x 3.4.1** and **Java 8**

Am I missing anything here? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: please try for a different input string(json validated)

Comment: Escaping double quotes with backslash inside description text should help you.

Comment: I don't have to escape the double quotes because the json is still valid and any online validator will not show any error for this json string.

Comment: Have you tried to annotate the description field with `@JsonRawValue` annotation?

Comment: Your input string is valid JSON, but the value of the description field is _not_ valid JSON. you need to replace the 0x201c with double quotes, _after_ you parse the container json string and extract the description value (similar to what oguzhan aygun suggested in the answer that was deleted).

Comment: @Rakesh I suggest you supply your MyClass Implementation. With a simple Java Bean implementation of MyClass I can't reproduce your issue. Everything works as intended.

Comment: @PaulGeorgPodlech I have added MyClass implementation in the OP. Thanks!

Comment: @Rakesh With exactly your MyClass implementation it works for me. I can't reproduce the problem. Maybe you can create a minimal example to reproduce on GitHub.